# Maintaining default visual properties with ControlTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

In order to apply a triggered animation to all `ToolTip`s in my app, I'm using a `ControlTemplate`.  However, when using a `ControlTemplate` the `ToolTip` loses all of its default visual properties as defined, I believe, by the theme.  How can I retain all properties except for those that I override?

Using the following code

```
<ToolTip Opacity="0.8">
  <ToolTip.Content>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label FontWeight="Bold" Background="DarkSlateBlue" Foreground="White">
        WpfApplication1
      </Label>
      <Label>
        Click to create another button
      </Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </ToolTip.Content>
</ToolTip>
```

I get the result I want:

[alt text http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1488/controltemplateno.png](http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/1488/controltemplateno.png)

But when I adjust the code to use a `ControlTemplate` as so:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="controltemplateToolTip" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
  <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />  
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToolTip.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource controltemplateToolTip}" />
</Style>
...
<ToolTip>
  <ToolTip.Content>
    <StackPanel>
      <Label FontWeight="Bold" Background="DarkSlateBlue" Foreground="White">
        WpfApplication1
      </Label>
      <Label>
        Click to create another button
      </Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </ToolTip.Content>
</ToolTip>
```

I get the following:

[alt text http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/8217/controltemplateyes.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/8217/controltemplateyes.png)

As you can see, the theme default border, background, etc. are not maintained.  I don't want to set these explicitly as I want them to adjust according to the user's theme.  How can I remedy this?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Also note that adding `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}` to the `ToolTip` style does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inherit ControlTemplate from theme style. But you don't have to. Use DataTemplates to achieve what you want. Here is a quick example:

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToolTip.Loaded">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
          <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ToolTipContentTemplate">
<StackPanel>
      <Label FontWeight="Bold" Background="DarkSlateBlue" Foreground="White">
        WpfApplication1
      </Label>
      <Label>
        Click to create another button
      </Label>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid>  
<Button Content="Hello">
<Button.ToolTip>
<ToolTip ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ToolTipContentTemplate}">
  <ToolTip.Content>
    Doesn't matter in this case
  </ToolTip.Content>
</ToolTip>
</Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

You can paste it to [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), and test it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Anvaka.  One note: I actually wanted the template content to be bound to `ToolTip.Content`, but that was simple to accomplish in your code with `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />`.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also, thank you for the heads up on Kaxaml.  So far I like it a lot more than XamlPad.